# Symfony Doctine сортировка по числам, затем буквам

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, symfony3

Мне нужно сортировать данные из бд. Например есть данные: 1,2,A,1C,1A,B,3,10, после применения сортировки я ожидаю увидеть: 1,1A,1C,2,3,10,A,B.
Когда-то у меня уже была такая задача, но без использования фреймворка. Я решил это таким запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM  table ORDER BY Name=0,-Name DESC, Name
```

Запрос рабочий и дает нужный результат. Как написать такой запрос при помощи querybuilder? У меня получается отсортировать так: A,B,1,1A,1C,2,3,10. При помощи такого запроса:

```
SELECT t
    FROM table t
        ORDER BY t.name+0 ASC, t.name
```

Но если если поставить знак равенства или минус в условие сортировки я получаю ошибку. Поэтому никак не могу сортировать данные нужным образом.
Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Native Query? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, если по каким-либо причинам нет возможности/не хочется использовать native SQL, можно воспользоваться механизмом [Query hints](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-hints) - т/е подсказать доктрине как трактовать ту или иную DQL конструкцию. Для этих целей необходимо реализовать соответствующий [SqlWalker](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html), а именно метод `walkOrderByClause`. При получении результатов следует указать имя hint'a для query:

```
$query = $ORMQueryBuilder->getQuery();
$query->setHint($yourHintName, $yourHintParams);

return $query->getResult();
```

После реализации этого класса возможно будет вставить в DQL вашу конструкцию в `ORDER BY`.